# Getting hidden input values with preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to get the value of `_fh` and `_nonce` with `preg_match`

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  name="signin">
<input type="hidden" name="_fh" value="cd5a29509482534507a7a999ad0e0943">
<input type="hidden" name="_nonce" value="7fe456a0902ba89b365f760cdeb37113">
```

Here is my attempt

```
$returnValue = preg_match('#<input(.*)name="_fh"(.*)value="(.*?)"#is', '<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  name="signin">
<input type="hidden" name="_fh" value="cd5a29509482534507a7a999ad0e0943">
<input type="hidden" name="_nonce" value="7fe456a0902ba89b365f760cdeb37113">

', $matches);
```

Result

```
array (
  0 => '<input type="hidden" name="_fh" value="cd5a29509482534507a7a999ad0e0943">
<input type="hidden" name="_nonce" value="7fe456a0902ba89b365f760cdeb37113"',
  1 => ' type="hidden" ',
  2 => ' value="cd5a29509482534507a7a999ad0e0943">
<input type="hidden" name="_nonce" ',
  3 => '7fe456a0902ba89b365f760cdeb37113',
)
```

Comment: Why you are using this approach, while you can get by simple `jquery.val`

Comment: @urfusion i need that value for curl

Comment: Try this way http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

Comment: While domdocument will work, it is likely loading more into memory than using a regular expression will. It will likely take longer to process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use regex for parsing HTML.

Recommended is to use [HTML DOM parser](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) like this:

```
$html = <<<EOF
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  name="signin">
<input type="hidden" name="_fh" value="cd5a29509482534507a7a999ad0e0943">
<input type="hidden" name="_nonce" value="7fe456a0902ba89b365f760cdeb37113">
EOF;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($html);

#echo $doc->saveHTML();
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$val1 = $xpath->query('//input[@name="_fh"]/@value')->item(0)->nodeValue;

$val2 = $xpath->query('//input[@name="_nonce"]/@value')->item(0)->nodeValue;

echo $val1 . PHP_EOL;
echo $val2 . PHP_EOL;
```

**Output:**

```
cd5a29509482534507a7a999ad0e0943
7fe456a0902ba89b365f760cdeb37113
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_match_all` to get nested arrays of the keys and values.

```
$form = '<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="signin">
<input type="hidden" name="_fh" value="cd5a29509482534507a7a999ad0e0943">
<input type="hidden" name="_nonce" value="7fe456a0902ba89b365f760cdeb37113">';

preg_match_all('# type="hidden" name="(.*?)" value="(.*?)"#is', $form, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  type="hidden" name="_fh" value="cd5a29509482534507a7a999ad0e0943"
            [1] =>  type="hidden" name="_nonce" value="7fe456a0902ba89b365f760cdeb37113"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => _fh
            [1] => _nonce
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => cd5a29509482534507a7a999ad0e0943
            [1] => 7fe456a0902ba89b365f760cdeb37113
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get value of all hidden inputs.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  name="signin">
<input type="hidden" name="_fh" value="cd5a29509482534507a7a999ad0e0943">
<input type="hidden" name="_nonce" value="7fe456a0902ba89b365f760cdeb37113">');
$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('input');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    if ($node->hasAttributes()) {
        foreach ($node->attributes as $attribute) {
            if ($attribute->nodeName == 'type' && $attribute->nodeValue == 'hidden') {
                $hidden_inputs[] = $node;
            }
        }
    }
}
foreach ($hidden_inputs as $node) {
    echo $node->getAttribute('value').'\n';
}
```

**[DEMO](http://phpio.net/s/12sn)**